# How to show currentLocation using GooglePlacesAutocomplete in expo project

Tags: react-native, expo, react-google-places-autocomplete

I have created an expo project using `npx create-expo-app test`.
I have installed below packages:

```
npx expo install expo-location
npx expo install react-native-google-places-autocomplete
```

Below is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~49.0.5",
    "expo-location": "~16.1.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Below is my `App.js` that make use of GooglePlacesAutocomplete:

```
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from "react-native-google-places-autocomplete";
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
navigator.geolocation = require("expo-location");

export default function App() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== "granted") {
        setErrorMsg("Permission to access location was denied");
        return;
      }

      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setLocation(location);
    })();
  }, []);

  let text = "Waiting..";
  if (errorMsg) {
    text = errorMsg;
  } else if (location) {
    text = JSON.stringify(location);
  }
  const homePlace = {
    description: "Home",
    geometry: { location: { lat: 48.8152937, lng: 2.4597668 } },
  };
  const workPlace = {
    description: "Work",
    geometry: { location: { lat: 48.8496818, lng: 2.2940881 } },
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
        placeholder="Search"
        minLength={2} // minimum length of text to search
        autoFocus={false}
        returnKeyType={"search"} // Can be left out for default return key https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#returnkeytype
        listViewDisplayed="auto" // true/false/undefined
        currentLocation={true}
        currentLocationLabel="Current location"
        nearbyPlacesAPI="GooglePlacesSearch" // Which API to use: GoogleReverseGeocoding or GooglePlacesSearch
        predefinedPlaces={[homePlace, workPlace]}
        fetchDetails={true}
        renderDescription={(row) => row.description} // custom description render
        onPress={(data, details = null) => {
          console.log(data);
        }}
        query={{
          // available options: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete
          key: "GOOLE_API_KEY",
          language: "en", // language of the results
        }}
        styles={{
          container: {
            flex: 1,
            width: "100%",
          },
          textInput: {
            backgroundColor: "#1faadb",
          },
        }}
        debounce={200}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

I have also accepted the permissions to retrieve user location from my IOS real device.
The **Current location** label of the prop `currentLocationLabel` is shown correctly in the input text after adding `navigator.geolocation = require("expo-location");`.

My issue is that when I press on the **Current location** label from the input text, the application crash with below message:

```
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentPosition' of undefined, js engine: hermes
```

How can I make sure the `currentLocation` label from the `predefinedPlaces` is retrieving the current location when I pressed on it ?

[image]

[image]